# how to change open dns settings for the router?

Tags: router, dns, opendns

Under the settings where the ip address can be selected. I only see my external ip address.
And any configuration(blocking sites) that I do from there wouldn't actually take effect. Unless I also try to change the dns server used by the computer itself.
I know that my router is already using open dns, because when I type a random website in the address bar:

> fafnalnfdlja.com

I'm redirected to this:

> http://guide.opendns.com/main?url=fafnalnfdlja.com

I want to block sites from the router using open dns. Is it possible in a free open dns account?

Comment: What brand and model is your router?

Comment: tp-link TL-WR340GD. I've already set the router to use open dns and its working, all I need to know now is how to configure from the open dns dashboard the settings.Since I can't see my routers ip address from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OpenDNS dashboard, you need to enter your **external** address, because that is what OpenDNS servers see. OpenDNS does not know the difference between your router, your PC, or your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem, but I'll take a shot anyway:

Try to follow [**these**](http://www.ehow.com/how_4556123_bad-web-sites-using-opendns.html) steps.